# it ~ to vs it ~ ing

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

When I first learned English, I was taught to use only "it ~ to" form as opposed to "it ~ ing" form, so I always thought the latter one is not grammatical.
But I heard a lot of native speakers actually using the second form, so I wondered if it's grammatical or it's ungrammatical but allowed in daily conversations.

For example:

> **It** was the first time **to** meet you.
>    **It** was the first time meet**ing** you.
>
> What is **it** like **to** have a child?
>   What is **it** like hav**ing** a child?

Comment: Briefly some native speaker intuitions: "It was the first time to meet you." is wrong. "It was the first time meeting you." sounds ok. However, to speak about a particular event in the past, like in the first two examples, I would say "It was the first time we met." Both the "to verb" and "verbing" forms are used for less specific, more general actions, like "to have a child" (in general), and "having a child" (in general), your next examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From M.Swan's *PEU*:

Infinitives are forms like (to) write, (to) stand. Unlike verb tenses (e.g. writes, stood), infinitives do not usually show the actual times of actions or events. They usually refer to actions and events in a more general way, rather like -ing forms. Besides simple infinitives like (to) write, there are also
progressive infinitives (e.g. (to) be writing), perfect infinitives (e.g. (to) have written) and passive infinitives (e.g. (to) be written).

An infinitive clause can be used **after be as a subject complement.**

> *Your task is to get across the river without being seen.*
>   *My ambition was to retire at thirty*

Sentences like these can also be constructed with preparatory **it**.

> *It is your task to get across the river without being seen.
>
>   It was my ambition to retire at thirty*

We can use -ing forms (e.g. smoking, walking) not only as verbs, but also like adjectives or nouns. When -ing forms are used as verbs or adjectives, they are
often called '**present participles**'. (This is not a very suitable name, because these forms can refer to the past, present or future.)  When they are used more like nouns, they are often called '**gerunds**'.

We can use **it** as a preparatory subject or object for an -ing form. **This is
usually informal.**

> *It's nice being with you. 
>
>   I thought it pointless starting before eight o'clock.*

This is common with **any/no good, any/no use and (not) worth.**

> *It's no good talking to him - he never listens.
>
>   Is it any use expecting them to be on time?
>
>   It's no use his/him apologising - I shall never forgive him.
>
>   I didn't think it worth complaining about the meal.*

Comment: Please use the OP examples.

Comment: The first pair seems dubious to me, but I'm not a native speaker. The second one is fine. Possible correction: _It was wonderful to meet you. It was wonderful meeting you._

Answer (score 0):

The second form is grammatically correct. The word ending with "-ing" is a gerund (while the word corresponding to "to" is an infinitive). Both infinitives and gerunds are nouns, so they are equivalent grammatically.

Which form is used in speech is down to preference, and, as you noted, the second form is more common.

Comment: No. Infinitives and gerunds are both verbs.

Comment: They are verbals that function as nouns.

Comment: @user178049 They are *verbal or deverbal* nouns!

Comment: @MaulikV They are clearly verbs  because they take a direct object (cf. "meeting/to meet **you**").

Answer (score -1):

Let's get it straight, your first pair of sentences is a complete mess!

- It was the first time **to meet** you.
- It was the first time **meeting** you.

Neither the option with the to-infinitive nor the option with the gerund really work here since the sentences are illogical and ungrammatical.

"**the first time to+verb**" is plain wrong *(bad English)* whether in the past or the present, or the future.

However, there seems to exist a construction "**the first time to+subject**" as in "*It was **the first time to Jupiter**. We didn't know what awaited us there.*". Guessing the meaning here is "**visit/journey/trip/travel**". However, as most sources say we need a possessive adjective with "**first time**". So your correct two sentences should be:

- It was **my** first time **to meet** you.
- It was **my** first time **meeting** you.

Notice, that the to-infinitive is stiffly formal. And by what I know the first sentence means "*something that was about to happen*" while the second one means "*something that happened*". However, in casual speech it's usually:

- It was the first time we met.
- It was my first time when I met you.

---

With the second pair the difference is vague but grammatically interpreted.

- What is it like **to have** a child?
- What is it like **having** a child?

According to **Cambridge Dictionary** - ["Verb patterns: verb + infinitive or verb + -ing"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/verb-patterns-verb-infinitive-or-verb-ing) some verbs can be followed by either a **to-infinitive** or **-ing** the "*difference in meaning is often small*" (quote from the reference):

However, here we can see a question form *("**What is... like**")* which we use when we are enquiring about experience. With this question form either the **to-infinitive** or the **-ing** will both mean the same thing. Although we could interpret them as with the verb "**like**":

- *The **-ing** form emphasises the verb itself.* (Implies enjoyment and liking)
- *The **to-infinitive** expresses habitual preference, something that we do not necessarily like or enjoy but consider as useful, right or wise.*

Based on this information we get:

- What is it like **to have** a child? *(A general question of possession)* - How does having a child change you and your life? This doesn't necessarily imply being pleased with having a child.
- What is it like **having** a child? *(A question of pleasure and satisfaction)* - What does one feel when he has a child? What emotions does one have? This implies being happy and enjoying the fact that you have a child.

To my own knowledge the **-ing** form usually conveys the idea of wanting to get into somebodies skin. To experience what they experience!

- What is it like **to be** a student? - You are asking about general knowledge and the idea.
- What is it like **being** a student? - You dire to become one. You want to know what it feels like to be one. You may as well be asking for personal experience.

Comment: In the latter, 'like' is not a verb, but a preposition. The canonical structure is 'To have a child is like what'.

Comment: Yeh, you are right. It's just that naturally "**what is it like**" functions in the same way the verb "**like**" does. So we could either interpret it as a question form with no difference in meaning between a *to-infinitive* and an *-ing* or with a slight difference in meaning as with the verb "like" followed by a *to-infinitive* or an *-ing*.

Comment: No, the verbal 'like' expresses enjoyment, as you said yourself. The preposition 'like' roughly means 'similar to'. And 'like' does not affect the verb form because 'to have a child/having a child' is the (logical) subject.

Comment: @user178049 You are looking at it from the wrong angle. imagine "**What is it like to have a child?**" to be "**Do you like to have a child?**" and "**What is it like having a child?**" to be "**Do you like having a child?**"

Comment: In "**What is it like**" you don't need the preposition! You need to address the whole question form which is used to ask for experience.

Comment: I don't see it. 'Do you like to have a child' is entirely different from 'What is it like to have a child'. Re: your subsequent comment, of course you don't need a preposition, because 'like' is the preposition. 'What is it like' ='It is like what'.

Comment: @user178049 I mean you don't need to focus on the preposition. The verb is "**is**" there but again that's not what one should focus on in this question form. I'm afraid you are wrong when you think that '*Do you like to have a child*' is entirely different from '*What is it like to have a child*'.